# Como hacer funcionar Google Chart con SQL (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-chart-api

Actualmente quiero hacer una consulta con un grafico de pie pero no logro que me muestre los resultados, no soy muy versado en php por lo que supongo debe ser un error de principiante.

Este es mi codigo:

```html
<?php
//Invoco el archivo de conexion:
include (conexion.php);

//Aqui hago mi consulta
$query = "SELECT leidos, reenviados FROM ex_tbl_campanas WHERE id_admin='196'";
$result = pg_query($query);

//Finalizo y comienzo el codigo html
<?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Language', 'Rating'],
                <?php
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo "['".$row['leidos']."', ".$row['reenviados']."],";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Most Popular Programming Languages',
                width: 900,
                height: 500,
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Display the pie chart -->
<div id="piechart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya vi el problema, aunque no me arroja los resultados de la forma en que quiero ya la consulta me la genera:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Leidos', 'Reenviados'],
                <?php
                if($result){
                    while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "['".$row['leidos']."', ".$row['reenviados']."],";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Most Popular Programming Languages',
                width: 900,
                height: 500,
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Display the pie chart -->
<div id="piechart"></div>
</body>
```

```html
<?php
//Invoco el archivo de conexion:
include (conexion.php);

//Aqui hago mi consulta
$query = "SELECT leidos, reenviados FROM ex_tbl_campanas WHERE id_admin='196'";
$result = pg_query($query);

//Finalizo y comienzo el codigo html
<?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Language', 'Rating'],
                <?php
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo "['".$row['leidos']."', ".$row['reenviados']."],";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Most Popular Programming Languages',
                width: 900,
                height: 500,
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Display the pie chart -->
<div id="piechart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```